# ElasticSearch - Whitespace analyzer for Dictionary<object, object>

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I'm trying to change a analyzer for an index's mapping. I understand how to do it for a simple `Text` type property but in .NET the class that I create the mapping from (using NEST's AutoMap() function), is of type `Dictionary<object, object>` which creates the index mapping that looks like this:

```
"attributes": {
  "properties": {
    "comparer": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "count": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "item": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "keys": {
      "properties": {
        "count": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "values": {
      "properties": {
        "count": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

When trying to change the analyzer for one of the fields inside the above mapping I'm getting the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "mapper [attributes.Title] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "mapper [attributes.Title] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I'm assuming from the error message that I cannot put a analyzer on something as generic as a `Dictionary<object, object>` but I need to find a approach that could work? (assuming it is possible)

Comment: `Dictionary<object, object>` is somewhat of an impedance mismatch with mapping in Elasticsearch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following NEST auto & manual fluent code solved the above problem for me. I believe there was an issue with Elastic Search trying to understand `Dictionary<object, object>` that caused it to never create the index. Using `Object<object>` did the trick:

```
elasticClient.CreateIndex("YOURINDEX", i => i
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<YOURTYPE>(m => m
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(props => props
                .Object<object>(o => o
                    .Name(x => x.Attributes)
                    .Properties(pprops => pprops
                        .Text(ps => ps
                            .Name(AttributeType.Title.ToString().ToLower())
                            .Analyzer("whitespace")
                            .Fielddata(true)
                            .Fields(f => f
                                .Keyword(k => k
                                    .Name("keyword")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```